# Sound lib haskell

Tags: audio, haskell

I need to find a sound library for haskell. I have followed instructions of some that are presented in haskell wiki http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Sound_data_structures but couldnt get any to work. All i need is to play audio files, regardless its format. 
I am developing a game with FunGen, and its time for music. I may have somo problems making them work togather, but I cant even play a simple sound example. 
Most of my problems are due to cabal installation, or dependancies I cant find anywhare. I am using Windows.

Comment: Which ones have you tried, and what are the problems?  Can you give error messages?

Comment: please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005592/play-a-wav-file-with-haskell)

hope something works for you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being on Windows is a major limitation in Haskell audio.  Most packages are bindings to C code, and they tend to be either Linux-centric (JACK, Alsa) or at best nominally cross-platform but in practice difficult to build and use on Windows.  You'll need to build or install the C library first before installing the Haskell binding.

Have you tried [OpenAL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenAL)?  It's probably the most well-suited for what you want to do.  If you install the [C OpenAL libraries](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx), the Haskell binding should be a fairly simple next step.  There are a few add-on packages that are meant to simplify some common tasks, like ALUT and Alure.

Otherwise, most other solutions would actually involve several packages that may not work well together.  [hsndfile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsndfile) and [hsndfile-vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsndfile-vector) are good for reading audio files (you'll need to have [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) installed), but they don't play sound.  [portaudio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/portaudio) will play audio (again, you'll need the [C portaudio library](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html)), but it hasn't been updated in a while (and some updates are badly needed).  You'll also need to be moderately familiar with a C compiler chain (e.g. MinGW or Cygwin) to install the necessary C libraries first.

Another way might be to bind to a dedicated audio language such as Supercollider or Csound.  This would be a rather heavyweight solution, but the bindings tend to be better-maintained and at least Csound should be easily installable on Windows (disclosure: I wrote the [hCsound](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hCsound) package).  [Sox](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sox) ([C library/executable](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)) might also work for you (I've never tried it on Windows, but it claims to work).

Comment: Good list, and very comprehensive. Only thing I'd add is that ALUT is deprecated. http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Lists/OpenAL%20Development/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fopenal%2FLists%2FOpenAL%20Development%2FDeprecated%20Alut%20Wav%20Loading%20Functions&FolderCTID=0x01200200BB72FB7EEB38514F8CD1A9372A031174

Comment: @rtperson - thanks for that; I've never used ALUT and basically thought of it as an audio-analog of GLUT (which, although mostly deprecated, is still fairly common).

Comment: when i try to install either hsndfile or hCsound, caball shouts that there is missing sndfile lib. I realize that i dont know how to install it, since copying a dll dindt work

Comment: @Illiax - that's the libsndfile (C library) dependency.  I think there's a windows installer from the project page at http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/, but you will probably need to make sure that wherever it installs to is on your path, which in turn depends on how your compiler chain is set up.  Sorry I can't really help with that, but you can probably find something if you search for "Haskell C dependency" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

> All i need is to play audio files, regardless its format.

Your best bet for this will be [hsndfile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsndfile), mentioned in John L.'s excellent answer above. But you may want to make your life easier initially. The WAV file format is [a very simple format](http://technology.niagarac.on.ca/courses/ctec1631/WavFileFormat.html) -- essentially consisting of raw PCM data with minimal headers prepended. Try to get a WAV file to play, and then broaden your horizons from there.

You will be fighting uphill against a lack of sample code -- and you may find yourself needing foreign memory pointers and other not-so-straightforward techniques -- but there's a decent sample for opening and reading a WAV file [here](https://github.com/kaoskorobase/hsndfile/blob/master/examples/interact.hs).

Also, when developing on Windows, learn to love the `-fno-ghci-sandbox` flag. It tells ghci that you're connecting to a library that uses its own thread local storage. It's often the only way to get certain external libraries to work in GHCi.