# Play a wav file with Haskell

Tags: haskell, audio, wav

Is there a simple, direct way to play a WAV file from Haskell using some library and possibly such that I play many sounds at once?

I'm aware of OpenAL but I'm not writing some advanced audio synthesis program, I just want to play some sounds for a little play thing. Ideally the API might be something like:

```
readWavFile :: FilePath -> IO Wave
playWave :: Wave -> IO ()
playWaveNonBlocking :: Wave -> IO ()
```

I'm *this* close to merely launching mplayer or something. Or trying to cat the wav directly to /dev/snd/ or somesuch.

Comment: You can happily invoke a 3rd party app. hmp3 uses [mpg123](http://code.haskell.org/~dons/code/hmp3/Core.hs) quite happily.

Comment: Yeah. Gonna try out this: http://tivo-mplayer.sourceforge.net/docs/mplayer-man.html#sect12 Quick enough for me.

Comment: No. It is not even simple to specify *what* you want to do. Do you want to be portably across multiple operating systems? Or do you only care about Linux? Are all the WAV files the same sample rate? Or do you need sample rate conversion as well? Is the sound card multichannel or not? Do you need low-latency/realtime? Or is high latency ok?

If you restrict yourself to only Linux, things can actually be worse.. you have OSS, Alsa, Jack, and more! Why have one working way of playing sound when you can have 10 broken ways :p

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is how to play multiple sounds on multiple channels at once with SDL. I think this answers the question criteria. WAV files, simple, Haskell, multiple channels.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Fix
import Graphics.UI.SDL as SDL
import Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer as Mix

main = do
  SDL.init [SDL.InitAudio]
  result <- openAudio audioRate audioFormat audioChannels audioBuffers
  classicJungle <- Mix.loadWAV "/home/chris/Samples/ClassicJungle/A4.wav"
  realTech      <- Mix.loadWAV "/home/chris/Samples/RealTech/A4.wav"
  ch1 <- Mix.playChannel anyChannel classicJungle 0
  SDL.delay 1000
  ch2 <- Mix.playChannel anyChannel realTech 0
  fix $ \loop -> do
    SDL.delay 50
    stillPlaying <- numChannelsPlaying
    when (stillPlaying /= 0) loop
  Mix.closeAudio
  SDL.quit

  where audioRate     = 22050
        audioFormat   = Mix.AudioS16LSB
        audioChannels = 2
        audioBuffers  = 4096
        anyChannel    = (-1)
```

Comment: Thank you! It is surprisingly tough to play audio using haskell.

Answer (score 9):

I realize this is not actually a convenient way to do it, but I had the test code lying around, so...

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
module Wav (main) where

import Fay.W3C.Events
import Fay.W3C.Html5

import Language.Fay.FFI
import Language.Fay.Prelude

main :: Fay ()
main = addWindowEventListener "load" run

run :: Event -> Fay Bool
run _ = do
    aud <- mkAudio
    setSrc aud "test.wav"
    play aud
    return False


mkAudio :: Fay HTMLAudioElement
mkAudio = ffi "new Audio()"

addWindowEventListener :: String -> (Event -> Fay Bool) -> Fay ()
addWindowEventListener = ffi "window['addEventListener'](%1,%2,false)"
```

There you go--playing a WAV file in Haskell thanks to the power of HTML5! All you have to do is launch a web browser instead of mplayer. :D

Comment: Where do you get `Fay.W3C.*` from?

Comment: @BenMillwood: From [what the test code was testing](https://github.com/isomorphism/fay-bindings/tree/master/Fay/W3C). I had mentioned working on those bindings in #fay a few days prior, which is what motivated this semi-joke response. (P.S. For anyone who isn't aware, Chris Done is the original author of [Fay](http://fay-lang.org/).)

Comment: Yeah, I got the joke, but the code actually looks pretty cool as well :)

Comment: @BenMillwood: I hacked up a boilerplate-o-matic code generator that parses the W3C's IDL files and spits out FFI bindings for Fay. The result is only partly usable right now, but you can pester me on IRC if you're interested in the status of it.

Answer (score 4):

using OpenAL through ALUT:

```
import Control.Monad
import Sound.ALUT

playSound :: IO ()
playSound =
  withProgNameAndArgs runALUTUsingCurrentContext $ \_ _ ->
  do
    (Just device) <- openDevice Nothing
    (Just context) <- createContext device []
    currentContext $= Just context
    buffer1 <- createBuffer $ Sine 440 0 1
    buffer2 <- createBuffer HelloWorld
    [source] <- genObjectNames 1
    queueBuffers source [buffer1,buffer2]
    play [source]
    sleep 4
    closeDevice device
    return ()

main = playSound
```

to load a wav file:

```
buffer3 <- createBuffer $ File "/path/to/file.wav"
```

credit goes to Chris Double: http://bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/haskell/openal.html

Answer (score 0):

```
module Main (main) where

import qualified SDL
import SDL.Mixer 

main :: IO ()
main = do
  SDL.initialize [SDL.InitAudio]
  withAudio defaultAudio 4096 $ do
    load "test.wav" >>= play
    SDL.delay 1000 
  SDL.quit
```

I was trying to play sound with Haskell and I found this board when I searched how to do this. Actually, I want to know some kind of solution in Japanese sites because I am Japanese, but I couldn't find such sites.
I tried the OpenAl one above and with a little revision I succeeded, but I want to have a result with a simpler way.
I use 'sdl2' and 'sdl2-mixer' library. To do this, I had to install sdl2 and sdl2-mixer library into my OS.

I am using DebianOS and I installed 'libsdl2-dev' and 'libsdl2-mixer-dev' with apt command.

```
sudo apt instll libsdl2-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev
```

(Because I installed these files many months ago, so my memory is ambiguous.)
I use 'stack' to launch a Haskell project.

```
stack new myproject
```

(`myproject` is the project name)

In the `myproject` folder I edited the `package.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- sdl2
- sdl2-mixer
```

and I also edited then `Main.hs` file in the `app` folder. That is the above code.
I put the `test.wav` file in the `myproject` folder and with the command:

```
stack run
```

I could play the test sound.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?